# Quiz using Visual Studio

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio

I want to make a little quiz about me using visual studio. My goal is to have 10 questions and 4 choices each. I've tried to stack buttons and then change 10 labels at different times and it's getting a little complicated... using arrays or/and loops how could i make this more efficient? This is what I have

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Form1.Visible = False
        Button2.Visible = False
        Button3.Visible = False
        Button4.Visible = False
        Button5.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
            Label3.Text = "1/10"
            Label4.Text = "Nice! That was Correct!
Great job!"
            Label4.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
        End If
        If Label3.Text = "1/10" Then
            Button2.Visible = True
        End If
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Or RadioButton2.Checked = True Or RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
            Label4.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
            Label4.Text = "Oh no! that was incorrect!
Try Again!"
        End If
        Button2.Text = "next"
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Label1.Text = "What is Luke Lopez's favorite color?"
        RadioButton4.Checked = False
        RadioButton1.Text = "Purple"
        RadioButton2.Text = "Burgundy"
        RadioButton3.Text = "Turqoise"
        RadioButton4.Text = "Brown"
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            Label3.Text = "2/10"
            Label4.Text = "Nice! That was Correct!
Great job!"
            Label4.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen

        End If
        If Label3.Text = "2/10" Then
            Button4.Visible = True
        End If
        If RadioButton3.Checked = True Or RadioButton2.Checked = True Or RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
            Label4.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
            Label4.Text = "Oh no! that was incorrect!
Try Again!"
        End If
        Button2.Text = "check"
        Button4.Text = "next"
        If Label3.Text = "2/10" Then
            Button3.Text = "next"
            Button4.Text = "Check"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Button3.Visible = False
        Label1.Text = "What is Luke Lopez's shoe size?"
        RadioButton1.Checked = False
        RadioButton1.Text = "7"
        RadioButton2.Text = "8.5"
        RadioButton3.Text = "7.5"
        RadioButton4.Text = "8"
        Button3.Visible = False
        If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
            Label3.Text = "3/10"
            Label4.Text = "Nice! That was Correct!
Great job!"
            Label4.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen

        End If
        If Label3.Text = "3/10" Then
            Button5.Visible = True
            Button4.Visible = False
            Button3.Visible = False
            Button2.Visible = False
            Button1.Visible = False
        End If
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Or RadioButton4.Checked = True Or RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
            Label4.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
            Label4.Text = "Oh no! that was incorrect!
Try Again!"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    End Sub
```

It's my first three questions and there are all the buttons and labels and radiobuttons checking and changing every click but I need this to be more efficient because I don't want to waste a lot of time and computer memory on this mini project.

Comment: He's some advice on efficient coding.  1) Give you're variables and controls useful and meaningful names, it increases readability and makes debugging and such more efficient.  2) Unless you've actually got good cause, hunting for efficiencies can often be less efficient.  You will likely find all the overheads of dealing with Arrays in this scenario uses more resources than coding as you have.  3)  Where possible, use Lists over Arrays, much simpler to deal with

Comment: 4) Computers now days have so many resources available, more often then not, the cause of any delay is what sits on the chair driving it

Comment: Final point,  the https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is specifically to deal with improving code.  You may get some advice there

Comment: It is not a good design to store your questions and answers in the code. Data (the questions and answers) should be separate from the code. The code will manipulate the data. You don't have to use a database. You can store the data in a text file that you write in Notepad.

Comment: Check if any answers help you handle this issue and if it helps, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If not, please provide more details here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments I talked about storing your data in a text file. This is what my text file looks like. Each record is on a single line and each field is separated by a pipe character |. I chose a pipe because you won't have any of that character in the text of your questions and answers.

```
1|Largest planet?|Jupiter|Venus|Saturn|Mars|1
2|Smallest planet?|Earth|Uranus|Mercury|Neptune|3
3|Comes closest to Earth?|Mars|Venus|Mercury|Jupiter|2
4|What planet is called the red planet?|Venus|Mars|Saturn|Neptune|2
5|What planet is furthest from Earth?|Saturn|Jupiter|Uranus|Neptune|4
6|How many planets in our solar system?|7|8|9|10|2
7|How many planets between Earth and Sun?|1|2|3|4|2
8|Which planet is said to have rings?|Jupiter|Uranus|Saturn|Neptune|3
```

You have been working with classes all along because a `Form` is a class. Classes can have Properties, methods and Events among other things. Now to the class, `QuestionAnswer`. The properties are pretty straight forward. The `Sub New` creates a new instance of the class and uses parameters to set all the properties of the class.

In the `Form.Load` `FillQuestionList` is called. This method uses the `File` class in `System.IO` (need to add an `Imports` for this). `ReadAllLines` returns an array of the all the lines in the file. We can loop through these lines and then split each line into fields. The little `c` after the `"|"` tells compiler that you intend a `Char` not a `String`. Now we can call the `Sub New` of `QuestionAnswer` providing all the properties from the parts of the line. This new instance is then added to the `QuestionList` so we can use it in the program.

Next, the `Load` event calls `DisplayQuestion`. This method will also be called from the `btnNext` click event. We get the index we want to display from the form level variable `CurrentQuestionIndex`. See how handy the class is to set the values we need. Loop through all the radio buttons clearing the `Tag` from the last question and clearing the check. The file provided the number of the correct answer. This is stored in the radio button's `Tag` property.

When the user clicks `btnAnswer` we get which radio button was selected and check the `Tag` property to see if the answer was correct. If yes, increment `Score` and display the score.

The `btnNext.Click` simply checks if we have reached the end of the list before incrementing the index and displaying the next question.

```
Public Class QuestionGame

    Private QuestionList As New List(Of QuestionAnswer)
    Private CurrentQuestionIndex As Integer
    Private Score As Integer

    Private Sub QuestionGame_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FillQuestionList()
        DisplayQuestion()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayQuestion()
        Dim QA = QuestionList(CurrentQuestionIndex)
        lblQuestion.Text = QA.Question
        RadioButton1.Text = QA.Answer1
        RadioButton2.Text = QA.Answer2
        RadioButton3.Text = QA.Answer3
        RadioButton4.Text = QA.Answer4
        For Each rb In Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)
            rb.Tag = ""
            rb.Checked = False
        Next
        Select Case QA.Correct
            Case 1
                RadioButton1.Tag = "Correct"
            Case 2
                RadioButton2.Tag = "Correct"
            Case 3
                RadioButton3.Tag = "Correct"
            Case 4
                RadioButton4.Tag = "Correct"
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillQuestionList()
        Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Questions.txt")
        For Each line In lines
            Dim parts = line.Split("|"c)
            QuestionList.Add(New QuestionAnswer(CInt(parts(0)), parts(1), parts(2), parts(3), parts(4), parts(5), CInt(parts(6))))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAnswer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAnswer.Click
        Dim rb = Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
        If rb IsNot Nothing AndAlso rb.Tag.ToString = "Correct" Then
            Score += 1
            lblScore.Text = Score.ToString
            MessageBox.Show("Correct!")
            btnAnswer.Enabled = False 'The user can't increase his score by clicking answer several times
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, wrong answer")
        End If
        btnNext.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        btnNext.Enabled = False 'user can't move to next question until he answers current question
        If CurrentQuestionIndex = QuestionList.Count - 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("This is the last question")
        Else
            CurrentQuestionIndex += 1
            DisplayQuestion()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class QuestionAnswer
    Public Property QuestionNumber As Integer
    Public Property Question As String
    Public Property Answer1 As String
    Public Property Answer2 As String
    Public Property Answer3 As String
    Public Property Answer4 As String
    Public Property Correct As Integer
    Public Sub New(Num As Integer, Ques As String, Ans1 As String, Ans2 As String, Ans3 As String, Ans4 As String, Cor As Integer)
        QuestionNumber = Num
        Question = Ques
        Answer1 = Ans1
        Answer2 = Ans2
        Answer3 = Ans3
        Answer4 = Ans4
        Correct = Cor
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save questions, options and answers to a database and then read them to a DataTable, every time you want to show the question, just use a DataRow from the DataTable. That means you don't need to edit questions like:

[image]

Use ['Label.TextChanged' event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to handle 'Label3.Text':

```
Private Sub Label3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.TextChanged
    Select Case Label3.Text
        Case "1/10"
            Button2.Visible = True
        Case "2/10"
            Button4.Visible = True
            Button3.Text = "next"
            Button4.Text = "Check"
        Case "3/10"
            ...
        ...
    End Select
End Sub
```

Use 'If ... Else ...' statement. For Example:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    '...


    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Label3.Text = "2/10"
        Label4.Text = "Nice! That was Correct! Great job!"
        Label4.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
    Else
        Label4.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
        Label4.Text = "Oh no! that was incorrect! Try Again!"
    End If

    'If RadioButton3.Checked = True Or RadioButton2.Checked = True Or RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
    '    Label4.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
    '    Label4.Text = "Oh no! that was incorrect! Try Again!"
    'End If

    '...
End Sub
```